# Function "fn:encode-for-uri" causes XSLT to error

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to URL Encode a string in XSLT but the function:

```
fn:encode-for-uri
```

breaks the script. I checked it out online and apparently it's part of the namespace

```
http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions
```

So i added the following line to the top of my XSLT file to no avail.

```
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
```

Any ideas? I stepped through it in Visual Studio and I got the exception:

```
Cannot find a script or an extension object associated with namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions'.
```

Any ideas?

-Ev

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Visual Studio uses a .NET XSLT processor --  that is XSLT 1.0 processor.

**The function [encode-for-uri()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-encode-for-uri) is a standard function only in XPath 2.0 / XQuery** . XSLT 1.0 processors only use XPath 1.0 and the `encode-for-uri()` function is not implemented and available.

In order to use this function you need an XSLT 2.0 processor, such as Saxon.NET or XQSharp.

Comment: +1 For a good answer. Also, in XSLT 1.0, whenever a fucntion name has a prefix it will be interpreted as an extension function.

Answer (score 2):

```
 <xsl:value-of select="encode-for-uri(...)"/>
```

Comment: See @Dimitre's good observation about the OP's XSLT version. However I want to add my agreement that it has always seemed confusing that the XSLT spec uses the "fn:" prefix for functions, which is associated with the namespace name "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions", when in fact you don't (need to) use that prefix when you call the functions.