# Does VS2012 use XSLT 1.0?

Tags: xslt, visual-studio-2012

[previous versions used XSLT 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4202068/57883)

Is this still the case in VS2012?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/340627/regexp-in-xslt/340865#340865

Answer (score 1):

> previous versions used XSLT 1
>
> Is this still the case in VS2012?

Yes.